# Looping through elements in an array and finding how many times it appears and adding each other element and pushing into a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I'm trying to solve a JavaScript problem that consists of three parts. I having problems solving step 2 and 3. This is something I'm trying to solve at work.

Step 1: count how many times an element `(0)` appears on an array *OK*

Step 2: add each value from left to right and push to a new array *Having difficulty here*

Step 3: print the new array with results *Having difficulty here*

For example:

```
let a = [1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 1];
Step 1: 0 // => 3 times
Step 2: [1+2, 0, 3+4, 0, 1];
Step 3: let newArry = [3, 0, 7, 0, 1] // => Resulting array
```

```js
/* Algorithm exercise:
*
*  Step 1: count how many times an element (0) appears on an array // => 0 appears 3 times
*  Step 2: Add each value that's not (0) from left to right and push to a * *new array
*  Step 3: Resulting array should be: let newArry = [3, 0, 7, 0, 1]
*  Explanation : [1+2, 0, 3+4, 0, 1];
*
*/

// Step 1: 1st try 
let a = [1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 1];
let counts = {};


for (let i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
 let num = a[i];
 console.info(`This is num now: ${num}`);
  
 
  counts[num] = counts[num] ? counts[num] + 1 : 1;
  
  console.info(`This is counts now after looping # ${i}: ${JSON.stringify(counts, undefined, 2)}`);
}

  console.table(`This is counts now: ${counts[0]}`);


// Step 1: 2nd try
let search = 0;
let occurences = a.filter(value => value === search).length;

console.info(`Found ${search} occuring ${occurences} times`);
```

Comment: Is this like an assignment or something?

Comment: Yes something like that.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: [How do I ask homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Please don't link your code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time and then your question is meaningless to those that come across it. As you can see, you can create functioning code snippets, right here in your question.

Comment: @ScottMarcus how did you do that? Thanks by the way

Comment: Your assignment rules make it sound like `0` should not be in the resulting array, yet you indicate that it should be. It actually looks like your saying you need to remove duplicate zeros in a row and leave the first one.

Comment: When composing a new question, look at the toolbar. There is a button that looks like `{}` 5 icons in from the left.

Comment: thanks @ScottMarcus will keep this in mind for next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: count how many times an element (0) appears on an array

```js
console.log([1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 1].filter(element => element===0 ).length);
```

Step 2 & 3

```js
const array = [1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ];

const result = array.reduce((prev, current) => {
  if (current) {
    if (prev[prev.length-1]) prev[prev.length-1]+=current;
    else prev.push(current);
  }
  else if (prev[prev.length-1] || prev.length===0) prev.push(current);
  return prev
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @Krzystof thanks, would you mind explaining it to me as if I where 5, cause I might be getting a bit lost is `current = currentValue(?)`  and `prev = new array(?)`

Comment: `array.prototype.reduce` method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each member of the array resulting in a single output value.

prev is the value returned by the reducer call from the index before, current is the value of array for the current index

so what i do is iterate over the array accumulating information into prev

Comment: It looks like your second program produces an incorrect result for `[ 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ]`

Answer (score 1):

In this answer, we will write `puzzle` to work like this -

```
const q =
  0

puzzle
  ( q
  , [ 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 1 ]
  , printf (`${q} appeared %s times. The result is %s`)
  )
  // 0 appeared 3 times. The result is 3,0,7,0,1

puzzle
  ( q
  , [ 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0 ]
  , printf (`${q} appeared %s times. The result is %s`)
  )
  // 0 appeared 6 times. The result is 3,0,7,0,26,0

puzzle
  ( 5
  , [ 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0 ]
  , printf (`5 appeared %s times. The result is %s`)
  )
  // 5 appeared 1 times. The result is 10,5,21
```

I can share this because it can teach you a lot but it's unlikely to be accepted by your teacher; not because it's a bad program, but it's improbable a beginner could write it on their own.

What's unique about this program is it completes all 3 steps simultaneously, using only one pass through your input array -

```
const None =
  Symbol ('None')

const puzzle = (query, [ a = None, b = None, ...rest ], then) =>
  a === None                     # 1
    ? then (0, [])

  : b === None                   # 2
    ? then
        ( Number (query === a)
        , [ a ]
        )

  : query === a && query === b   # 3
    ? puzzle
        ( query
        , [ b, ...rest ]
        , (count, result) =>
            then
              ( count + 1
              , result
              )
        )

  : query !== a && query !== b   # 4
    ? puzzle
        ( query
        , [ a + b, ...rest ]
        , then
        )

  : puzzle                       # 5
      ( query
      , [ b, ...rest ]
      , (count, result) =>
          then
            ( count + Number (query === a)
            , [ a, ...result ]
            )
      )
```

`puzzle` is defined as a recursive function using [mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) where we reason about the values we're processing in a particular way. Refer to the numbered comments above as we break it down below:

1. **(base)** When we have no `a`, it means the input is an *empty* array; there is nothing left to count, no values to add together, no duplicate values to collapse. In this case, return the *empty* result: `0` for count, and `[]` for the output array.
2. **(inductive: `a` is not none)** When we have an `a` but no `b`, it means we only have one item left; the *singleton* array. Here we cannot add two values together or collapse duplicate values because we only have *one* value. In this case, return the *singleton* result: `Number (query === a)` for the count, which casts a boolean to a number, and the *singleton* output array, `[ a ]`
3. **(inductive: `a` is not none, `b` is not none)** When we have an `a` and a `b`, it means we have enough values to start handling the more complex operations of our function. I don't want to add numbers that match the query, nor do I want to add `a` to the result if it is a duplicate, so I have to check this first. When query matches both `a` *and* `b`, a duplicate has been found. In this case, repeat the puzzle without `a`. When we get result of the smaller puzzle, we increment the count using `count + 1` because our query matched `a`. This code branch handles *removal* of a duplicate element, so there's nothing new to add to the output array, `result`.
4. **(inductive: `a` is not none, `b` is not none, `query` does not match both)** We have an `a` and a `b` and the query does not match *both*. If it matches *neither* then we know we can add `a` and `b` together. In this case, repeat the puzzle with `a + b`. Since the query did not match either, we know there's no count to update. The output array is also unchanged because it's possible the new number we created will get added to more adjacent elements before appearing in the output. Because `count` and `result` are unchanged in this code branch, `then` is passed through directly.
5. **(inductive: `a` is not none, `b` is not none, `query` matches either `a` or `b`)** We have an `a` and a `b` and we know the query matches one *or* the other. It doesn't matter which is a match; either way the values are not duplicates and should not be removed, nor can the values be added together. In this case, repeat the puzzle with `b`, increment the count if `a` matches the query, and prepend `a` to the result. This is the only code branch where values get inserted into the output array.

---

`printf` is defined for demo purposes as -

```
const printf = f =>
  console.log .bind (console, f)
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
const printf = f =>
  console.log .bind (console, f)

const None =
  Symbol ('None')

const puzzle = (query, [ a = None, b = None, ...rest ], then) =>
  a === None
    ? then (0, [])

  : b === None
    ? then
        ( Number (query === a)
        , [ a ]
        )
  
  : query === a && query === b
    ? puzzle
        ( query
        , [ b, ...rest ]
        , (count, result) =>
            then (count + 1, result)
        )

  : query !== a && query !== b
    ? puzzle
        ( query
        , [ a + b, ...rest ]
        , then
        )

  : puzzle
      ( query
      , [ b, ...rest ]
      , (count, result) =>
          then
            ( count + Number (query === a)
            , [ a, ...result ]
            )
      )

const q =
  0
  
puzzle
  ( q
  , [ 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 1 ]
  , printf (`${q} appeared %s times. The result is %s`)
  )
  // 0 appeared 3 times. The result is 3,0,7,0,1

puzzle
  ( q
  , [ 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0 ]
  , printf (`${q} appeared %s times. The result is %s`)
  )
  // 0 appeared 6 times. The result is 3,0,7,0,26,0

puzzle
  ( 5
  , [ 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0 ]
  , printf (`5 appeared %s times. The result is %s`)
  )
  // 5 appeared 1 times. The result is 10,5,21
```

Comment: thanks for the very detail explanation @user633183 this a very good example and code, how in the world did you come up with this? Thanks

Comment: I have studied and written a lot about [recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A633183+%5Brecursion%5D). The technique is usually taught on smaller problems using just 2 cases, but this particular problem, due to its complexity, involves a 5-case inductive reasoning tree. Once you're comfortable writing the logical statements for 2 cases, learning how to support additional cases becomes easier. If you have other questions, let me know :D